# Running tcpdump, tee and scp

Tags: shell, pipe, tcpdump

I'm trying to run the following:

```
$ tcpdump -l -X -i eth1 -n tcp port <port> | tee capture.txt | \
       scp capture.txt  root@10.3.3.227:/home/checker/
```

1. `tcpdump -l -X -i eth1 -n tcp port <port>`

   In step #1 I'm capturing packets, using "-l" to to make standard out line-buffered, so that it will write each packet as it arrives.
2. `tee capture.txt`

   In step #2 `man tee`: "The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy in zero or more files." The output is unbuffered.
3. `scp capture.txt root@<remote-IP>:/home/`

   In step #3 I'm send the capture.txt file to a remote host.

#### The problem

If I simply perform steps #1 and #2, ALL packets are captured on the specified port. However, if I also use step #3 the `capture.tx`t does NOT contain all the packets (only a few)... This is killing me because I had this running OK just a few minutes ago!

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

The `tee` command writes data to the output file as it receives it, but `scp` copies the file immediately and only copies it once. Since every command in the pipeline runs simultaneously (or nearly so), you only get a few (or no) packets output to the *capture.txt* file before the file gets copied by `scp`.

There are a couple ways to do what you seem to want to do.

If you want to copy a few packets from `tcpdump`, and then transfer the file to the remote host after it finishes, you can use the `-c` option to terminate `tcpdump` after it captures that number of packets. Separate your `scp` command from the pipeline using a semi colon so it gets executed after the `tcpdump` and `tee` commands complete:

```
tcpdump -l -c 10  | tee  /tmp/capture.txt; scp /tmp/capture.txt root@remotehost:/tmp
```

Or, if you want to see packets in real-time and also copy them in realtime, you could use `tee` to output the packets to /dev/tty so you can see them, and them pipe them into an `ssh` command that writes them to a file on the remote host:

```
tcpdump -l   | tee /dev/tty | ssh root@remotehost "cat > /tmp/capture.txt"
```

Note that without the `-c` option here, tcpdump will run until you kill it.

If you wanted the packets stored in a local capture.txt file as well as the remote, you could use multiple `tee` commands:

```
tcpdump -l   | tee /tmp/capture.txt | tee /dev/tty | ssh root@remotehost "cat > /tmp/capture.txt"
```

Comment: I've just noticed an issue.

The capute.txt file that is sent to the remote host, on a second run of the tcpdump, is incremented instead of replaced...

How do I overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure which of the command lines I provided you're using, but none of them should be appending to the file. "tee" will overwrite the output file with each run, and the ">" operator will also overwrite the file. Can you give more details? Are you running on Linux?

Comment: Yes, I'm running Debian Linux. I'm using:

tcpdump -l   | tee /dev/tty | ssh root@remotehost "cat > /tmp/capture.txt"

I've tried to "echo /dev/null > capture" and "rm" the capture.txt but none of these are working =\ The file on the remote host keeps incrementing...

Comment: Is it possible that you have one of the commands running in the background or in another terminal window?

Comment: nope =\ I'm trying to "fix" this with something like this: 
cat > /home/checker/temp.txt | cp /home/checker/temp.txt /home/checker/capture.txt | echo "" /home/checker/temp.txt

The last part is to make sure the temp.txt is erased and, on the next tcpdump iteration, it is not incremented but instead written as a brand new file. But so far, this is not working (guess the cp is not working properly). Any ideias to copy a file's content into another?

Comment: Forget what I wrote before. I think the problem is explained here http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ (ctrl+F for "tcpdump"). Also, take a look at the last post here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/how-to-process-pipe-tcpdumps-output-in-realtime

Answer (score 3):

It is not guaranteed that tee finished writing capture.txt when scp reads it. What you could do is use the stdout of tee and pipe it through ssh like this:

```
tcpdump -l -X -i eth1 -n tcp port <port> | tee capture.txt | \
  ssh root@10.3.3.227 'cat > /home/checker/capture.txt'
```

Comment: Thaks a lot! It worked! :D

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that the file you're copying via `scp` is copied at a moment in time and not continuously, so you end up with a fragment of the contents of that file on server 10.3.3.227.

Try this instead:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -l -X -i eth1 -n <tcp port> | tee capture.txt | \
    ssh root@10.3.3.227 'cat > /home/checker/capture.txt
```