# Sniffing packets realtime

Tags: tcpdump

I've been using tcpdump and it's good, but it exhibits issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979033/libpcap-not-receiving-in-real-time-seems-to-be-buffering-packets). Other programs like hexinject, tcpflow, and tracedump all use pcap so they delay a bit before displaying the packets.

I've also used [raw-sockets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket) which does not lag, but I am unable to get port numbers with raw sockets.

I've looked at the docs for tcpdump, and there seems to be [`--immediate-mode`](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.txt). I'm trying to get tcpdump to stop delaying sending its packets.

My current versions are:

- tcpdump version 4.6.2
- libpcap version 1.6.2

Is there a patch for tcpdump [like this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.os.openbsd.tech/40063) or another cli that doesn't delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a patch for tcpdump [like this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.os.openbsd.tech/40063)

Yeah, there's [this](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/commit/d71793791fa0823f25fa9adaa2bb99797197337f#diff-7e660399caf44361997e2346920eb314), which, like that patch, adds a flag to turn immediate mode on...

...except that it's not BPF-specific (so it's not restricted to *BSD, OS X, and Solaris 11), and uses `--immediate-mode` rather than `-b`, and it's already in the standard tcpdump 4.7.x releases, so if you have tcpdump 4.7.x or later you don't *have* to apply the patch.

What kind of patch are you looking for?  One that doesn't require a recent version of libpcap with an API to turn on immediate mode?  If so, either that patch won't work on some OSes or will have to do OS-dependent things (and, unfortunately, there's not some simple ioctl you can do on Linux, so there might not *be* an OS-dependent way of turning buffering off for your OS).

On the other hand, you could try reducing the timeout to, say, 1/10 of a second (use 100 rather than 1000 in `pcap_open_live()` or `pcap_set_timeout()`) or even 1/100 of a second (use 10 rather than 1000 in `pcap_open_live()` or `pcap_set_timeout()`).