# "tail -f" using "tcpdump -r"

Tags: tail, tcpdump, real-time, pcap

To display content of `pcap` file , we use :

```
tcpdump -r /Path/to/syscontection.pcap;
```

However, this command line does not follow the pcap file on realtime , like `tail -f` which follows a plain text .

- Is there an option with `tcpdump` which acts like `-f` of `tail` ?

OR

- Is there an option with `tail` that can read `pcap` file?

OR

- Something else ?

Comment: tcpdump acts exactly what you want when running with no parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process/pipe TCPDUMPs output in realtime](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/how-to-process-pipe-tcpdumps-output-in-realtime).

I also recommend checking the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) before asking a question, it might save you some time.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. He is asking about tcpdump's input not output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
tail -c +1 -f /Path/to/syscontection.pcap | tcpdump -l -r -
```

Comment: This will not work when we want to read from multiple files, what will be the solution for `tcpdump -l -r file1,file2` e.g. ?
`tail -c +1 -f file1 -f file2 | tcpdump -l -r -`  will not work since tail will output some extra lines while tailing multiple files

Comment: @Dipto I guess you could simply two or more of these pipe command lines in backround. `( tail -c +1 -f a.pcap | tcpdump  -l -r - & tail -c +1 -f b.pcap | tcpdump  -l -r - & )`

Comment: Thanks. But what I found is `tcpdump -r /Path/to/pcap` is able to follow the file in realtime as it is. May be OP is facing another problem https://superuser.com/questions/735017/why-does-tcpdump-take-so-long-to-read-pcap-files/735053#735053