# tcpdump - realtime dns logger with pipe

Tags: dns, tcpdump

I want to get DNS A records in realtime with tcpdump on stdout.

```
tcpdump -i any dst port 53 | awk '/ A\? / {u = NF - 1; print $u}' | sed 's/.$//g'
```

There is no output coming from the above line. Tcpdump seems still buffering on pipes or something. I've tested `-l` `--immediate-mode` and `-U` as well.

The line below outputs properly (in realtime) but obviously unfiltered (no grep/awk):

```
tcpdump -i any dst port 53
```

If i send its output lines manually to the awk/sed commands above they do work properly.

Everything tested on Arch Linux and Android 8.1 (bash, tcpdump 4.9.2).

Question: How to get tcpdump output in realtime with pipe/awk/sed?

There is an old thread from 2011 that doesn't fix the problem.
[How to process/pipe TCPDUMPs output in realtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/how-to-process-pipe-tcpdumps-output-in-realtime)

Comment: did you turn off buffering in `awk` and in `sed` and in ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: I've tried `sudo unbuffer tcpdump -i any dst port 53 | unbuffer awk '/ A\? / {u = NF - 1; print $u}' | unbuffer sed 's/.$//g'` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this variant:

```
tcpdump -l -i any dst port 53 | stdbuf -oL awk '/ A\? / {u = NF - 1; print $u}' | sed 's/.$//g'
```

You have to buffer every line of tcpdump output, option `-l` is used for that.

From `man tcpdump`:

```
-l     Make stdout line buffered.  Useful if you want to see the data while capturing it.
```

To make awk output line buffering [stdbuf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562344/what-does-grep-line-buffering-do) is used.

```
-o, --output=MODE  adjust standard output stream buffering
If MODE is 'L' the corresponding stream will be line buffered.
```

Comment: Works on Arch Linux but not on Android (no `stdbuf` binary). Any solution for Android?